# Size of prototype mask and Mask produced in Yolact

Tags: computer-vision, real-time, image-segmentation

I read the paper explaining Yolact and Yolact++. I'm confused with the mask size and prototype mask. There is an illustration of protonet and the output from protonet is of size 138 * 138 * 32. Is this the size of protomask? I have read in the paper saying that the algorithm produces an image sized mask. So Please clarify the size of the mask produced.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example an input with the following size:
(H,W,C) = (512,512,3)

The **protonet** will give you the following output size (a.k.a proto-masks): (128,128,32) - where **32=Number of Protos**. It is 1/4 of the input size.

The protos are being used for getting the mask by a linear combination of them, with the corresponding coefficients predicted by the prediction module.
Therefore you will have a mask, with the size (128,128). Then a crop is being done on this mask, the cropping is done according to the bbox prediction (after NMS).

The bbox values can be related as relative to the image size, therefore (0.5,0.5,1.,1.) which corresponds to (256.,256.,512.,512.) in the input image, are (64.,64.,128.,128.) in the mask created by the protos